# Creating a Mule project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, mule, mule-studio

I have started working with Mule. I am working with Mule Studio. This looks good.
But when I want to create a Mule project in Eclipse I am struck.
Please suggest me how I can create a Mule project in Eclipse.

Comment: By "in Eclipse" do you mean "not in Mule Studio"? I'm asking because Mule Studio is built on Eclipse.

Comment: I meant plain Eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Option 1: With Mule IDE Plugin for Eclipse.

You can use the Mule IDE plugin from eclipse. This helps in creating the mule project in eclipse.

To add plugins please start eclipse and navigate to  **help->install new software -> Add site and select the artifacts presented**

Add muleide (mule plugin) - http://dist.muleforge.org/mule-ide/updates/3.4/

Then restart Eclipse after the plugin installation and You can create a Mule Project under the New Project option.

### Option 2: Without Mule IDE.  With Maven and Eclipse.

Open Command prompt.
Run the following Maven command to create a Mule project.

```
mvn org.mule.tools:mule-project-archetype:3.3.0:create -DartifactId=MySampleMuleProj -DmuleVersion=3.3.0
```

Then run the follwoing commands.

```
mvn clean compile
mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse
```

After this open Eclipse IDE
Import this project into the eclipse workspace.

> *Note: Use Import "Existing Maven Project" option  for importing this project.*

To run the Mule project in eclipse forllow the below steps.

```
1. Goto Run -> Run Configurations in eclipse and select Java Application.
2. Click on New launch configuration and enter name of the configuration(for ex. MyMuleProj).
3. Select MyMuleProj as a project and Main class "org.mule.MuleServer".
4. Click on Arguments tab and enter Program arguments "-config src/main/app/mule-config.xml".
```

You can see the Mule project up and Running.

:)  Happy Learning.

Comment: What to do if I receive an exception?: `09.12.2015 12:01:10.425 ERROR MuleServer:451 - 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Failed to invoke lifecycle phase "start" on object: org.mule.util.queue.DelegateQueueManager@7c8c70d6
Code                  : MULE_ERROR-70228
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteQuietly(Ljava/io/File;)Z (java.lang.NoSuchMethodError)`

Comment: Root Exception stack trace:
`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteQuietly(Ljava/io/File;)Z
 at org.mule.util.journal.TransactionJournalFile.clear(TransactionJournalFile.java:149)
 at org.mule.util.journal.TransactionJournal.clear(TransactionJournal.java:135)
 at org.mule.util.journal.queue.AbstractQueueTransactionJournal.clear(AbstractQueueTransactionJournal.java:121)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)`

Answer (score 1):

You can import your existing project in eclipse or if you've a Maven project, create an `Other` project and select Maven-> Checkout Maven Projects from SCM or create a Java project. There are so many ways to do it.

I run my mule project in eclipse through `MuleServer` class and passing `mule-config.xml` as program argument.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Mule Anypoint Studio is built on Eclipse. If you want to import any maven project, then do this : mvn clean compile
mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse