# How to override mule config file name in Mule Studio?

Tags: mule, mule-studio

MuleStudio or its plugin for eclipse uses mule-config.xml file by default. Is there an option to override the file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options.

1. Right click on the Mule Project and go to

   Run As --> Run COnfigurations

   Then Select `Java Application`. Then right click and select `New`
   Add your config file name as shown in the picture and run it.
   [image: Configuration pic]
2. Create a mule-deploy.properties and keep it in the src/main/app folder. 
   Add the configuration resource entry to it. This will be helpful when you package and deploy mule application onto a mule standalone server.

   config.resources=my-mule-config.xml

Refer to the following link for more detials on Mule in Eclipse.

[Creating a Mule project in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387007/creating-a-mule-project-in-eclipse)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can rename the file by right clicking on it and select refactor or select the file and click F2 to rename it and then run the application as Mule run configurations.