# NoSuchMethodError exception when run Mule Application from Ecplise

Tags: java, maven, mule, mule-studio, nosuchmethoderror

I am trying to move application from Anypount Studio to Eclipse according to this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387007/creating-a-mule-project-in-eclipse) 
I configured Run configuration, but when started have exception:

```
09.12.2015 13:27:46.462 WARN  JdkVersionUtils:328 - We are looking into adding support for this JDK version. Use it at your own risk.
09.12.2015 13:27:46.491 INFO  MuleServer:287 - Mule Server initializing...
09.12.2015 13:27:46.754 WARN  JdkVersionUtils:328 - We are looking into adding support for this JDK version. Use it at your own risk.
09.12.2015 13:27:46.771 INFO  AbstractLifecycleManager:51 - Initialising RegistryBroker
09.12.2015 13:27:47.009 INFO  MuleArtifactContext:510 - Refreshing org.mule.config.spring.MuleArtifactContext@1b1473ab: startup date [Wed Dec 09 13:27:47 MSK 2015]; root of context hierarchy
09.12.2015 13:27:47.134 INFO  XmlBeanDefinitionReader:315 - Loading XML bean definitions from URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/org/mule/modules/mule-module-spring-config/3.5.0/mule-module-spring-config-3.5.0.jar!/registry-bootstrap-mule-config.xml]
09.12.2015 13:27:47.662 INFO  XmlBeanDefinitionReader:315 - Loading XML bean definitions from URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/org/mule/modules/mule-module-spring-config/3.5.0/mule-module-spring-config-3.5.0.jar!/minimal-mule-config.xml]
09.12.2015 13:27:48.159 INFO  DefaultListableBeanFactory:663 - Overriding bean definition for bean '_muleConfiguration': replacing [Generic bean: class [org.mule.config.spring.MuleConfigurationConfigurator]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=initialise; destroyMethodName=null; defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/org/mule/modules/mule-module-spring-config/3.5.0/mule-module-spring-config-3.5.0.jar!/minimal-mule-config.xml]] with [Generic bean: class [org.mule.config.spring.MuleConfigurationConfigurator]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=initialise; destroyMethodName=null; defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/org/mule/modules/mule-module-spring-config/3.5.0/mule-module-spring-config-3.5.0.jar!/minimal-mule-config.xml]]
09.12.2015 13:27:48.160 INFO  DefaultListableBeanFactory:663 - Overriding bean definition for bean '_muleConfiguration': replacing [Generic bean: class [org.mule.config.spring.MuleConfigurationConfigurator]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=initialise; destroyMethodName=null; defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/org/mule/modules/mule-module-spring-config/3.5.0/mule-module-spring-config-3.5.0.jar!/minimal-mule-config.xml]] with [Generic bean: class [org.mule.config.spring.MuleConfigurationConfigurator]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=initialise; destroyMethodName=null; defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/org/mule/modules/mule-module-spring-config/3.5.0/mule-module-spring-config-3.5.0.jar!/minimal-mule-config.xml]]
09.12.2015 13:27:48.166 INFO  DefaultListableBeanFactory:663 - Overriding bean definition for bean '_muleNotificationManager': replacing [Generic bean: class [org.mule.config.spring.ServerNotificationManagerConfigurator]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=initialise; destroyMethodName=null; defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/org/mule/modules/mule-module-spring-config/3.5.0/mule-module-spring-config-3.5.0.jar!/minimal-mule-config.xml]] with [Generic bean: class [org.mule.config.spring.ServerNotificationManagerConfigurator]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=initialise; destroyMethodName=null; defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/org/mule/modules/mule-module-spring-config/3.5.0/mule-module-spring-config-3.5.0.jar!/minimal-mule-config.xml]]
09.12.2015 13:27:48.167 INFO  DefaultListableBeanFactory:663 - Overriding bean definition for bean '_muleNotificationManager': replacing [Generic bean: class [org.mule.config.spring.ServerNotificationManagerConfigurator]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=initialise; destroyMethodName=null; defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/org/mule/modules/mule-module-spring-config/3.5.0/mule-module-spring-config-3.5.0.jar!/minimal-mule-config.xml]] with [Generic bean: class [org.mule.config.spring.ServerNotificationManagerConfigurator]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=initialise; destroyMethodName=null; defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/org/mule/modules/mule-module-spring-config/3.5.0/mule-module-spring-config-3.5.0.jar!/minimal-mule-config.xml]]
09.12.2015 13:27:48.186 INFO  XmlBeanDefinitionReader:315 - Loading XML bean definitions from URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/org/mule/modules/mule-module-spring-config/3.5.0/mule-module-spring-config-3.5.0.jar!/mule-spring-config.xml]
09.12.2015 13:27:48.212 INFO  XmlBeanDefinitionReader:315 - Loading XML bean definitions from URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/org/mule/modules/mule-module-spring-config/3.5.0/mule-module-spring-config-3.5.0.jar!/default-mule-config.xml]
09.12.2015 13:27:48.332 INFO  DefaultListableBeanFactory:663 - Overriding bean definition for bean '_muleSystemModel': replacing [Root bean: class [org.mule.model.seda.SedaModel]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=initialise; destroyMethodName=dispose] with [Root bean: class [org.mule.model.seda.SedaModel]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=initialise; destroyMethodName=dispose]
09.12.2015 13:27:48.334 INFO  DefaultListableBeanFactory:663 - Overriding bean definition for bean '_defaultThreadingProfile': replacing [Generic bean: class [org.mule.config.ChainedThreadingProfile]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=initialise; destroyMethodName=null; defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/org/mule/modules/mule-module-spring-config/3.5.0/mule-module-spring-config-3.5.0.jar!/minimal-mule-config.xml]] with [Generic bean: class [org.mule.config.ChainedThreadingProfile]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=initialise; destroyMethodName=null; defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/org/mule/modules/mule-module-spring-config/3.5.0/mule-module-spring-config-3.5.0.jar!/default-mule-config.xml]]
09.12.2015 13:27:48.335 INFO  DefaultListableBeanFactory:663 - Overriding bean definition for bean '_defaultRetryPolicyTemplate': replacing [Generic bean: class [org.mule.retry.policies.NoRetryPolicyTemplate]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=initialise; destroyMethodName=null; defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/org/mule/modules/mule-module-spring-config/3.5.0/mule-module-spring-config-3.5.0.jar!/minimal-mule-config.xml]] with [Generic bean: class [org.mule.retry.policies.NoRetryPolicyTemplate]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=initialise; destroyMethodName=null; defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/org/mule/modules/mule-module-spring-config/3.5.0/mule-module-spring-config-3.5.0.jar!/default-mule-config.xml]]
09.12.2015 13:27:48.338 INFO  XmlBeanDefinitionReader:315 - Loading XML bean definitions from URL [file:/C:/Users/Maya/workspace/appservices/src/main/app/appservices.xml]
09.12.2015 13:27:48.488 INFO  DefaultListableBeanFactory:663 - Overriding bean definition for bean 'appFlow1': replacing [Root bean: class [org.mule.construct.Flow]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=initialise; destroyMethodName=dispose] with [Root bean: class [org.mule.construct.Flow]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=initialise; destroyMethodName=dispose]
09.12.2015 13:27:49.361 INFO  DefaultListableBeanFactory:596 - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@48a12036: defining beans [_muleSimpleRegistryBootstrap,_muleNotificationManager,_muleConfiguration,._muleNotificationManager:notification.1,._muleNotificationManager:notification.2,._muleNotificationManager:notification.3,._muleNotificationManager:notification.4,._muleNotificationManager:notification.5,._muleNotificationManager:notification.6,._muleNotificationManager:notification.7,._muleNotificationManager:notification.8,._muleNotificationManager:notification.9,._muleNotificationManager:notification.10,_defaultInMemoryQueueStore,_defaultPersistentQueueStore,_defaultInMemoryObjectStore,_defaultPersistentObjectStore,_defaultUserObjectStore,_defaultTransientUserObjectStore,_muleQueueManager,_muleObjectStoreManager,_defaultThreadingProfile,_defaultMessageDispatcherThreadingProfile,_defaultMessageRequesterThreadingProfile,_defaultMessageReceiverThreadingProfile,_defaultServiceThreadingProfile,_defaultRetryPolicyTemplate,_muleExpressionLanguage,_muleCustomEditorConfigurer,_muleObjectNameProcessor,_mulePropertyPlaceholderProcessor,_muleParentContextPropertyPlaceholderProcessor,_muleSystemModel,_muleAnnotationsProcessor,_muleTransformerAnnotationProcessor,_muleSecurityManager,_muleMessageProcessingManager,_muleEndpointFactory,_muleStreamCloserService,_converterResolver,_muleLockFactory,_muleLockProvider,_muleProcessingTimeWatcher,appFlow1,.appFlow1:inbound-endpoint.11,.appFlow1:jaxws-service.12,.appFlow1:jaxws-service.12:inInterceptors.13,.appFlow1:jaxws-service.12:outInterceptors.14,.appFlow1:component.15]; root of factory hierarchy
09.12.2015 13:27:49.908 INFO  TransactionJournal:61 - Using files for tx logs C:\Users\Maya\workspace\appservices\.\.mule\queue-tx-log\tx1.log and C:\Users\Maya\workspace\appservices\.\.mule\queue-tx-log\tx2.log
09.12.2015 13:27:49.923 INFO  TransactionJournal:61 - Using files for tx logs C:\Users\Maya\workspace\appservices\.\.mule\queue-xa-tx-log\tx1.log and C:\Users\Maya\workspace\appservices\.\.mule\queue-xa-tx-log\tx2.log
09.12.2015 13:27:49.959 INFO  AbstractLifecycleManager:34 - Initialising model: _muleSystemModel
09.12.2015 13:27:50.033 WARN  GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor:113 - Invalid JavaBean property 'port' being accessed! Ambiguous write methods found next to actually used [public void org.mule.endpoint.URIBuilder.setPort(java.lang.String)]: [public void org.mule.endpoint.URIBuilder.setPort(int)]
09.12.2015 13:27:50.188 INFO  AbstractLifecycleManager:40 - Initialising connector: connector.http.mule.default
09.12.2015 13:27:50.322 INFO  FlowConstructLifecycleManager:76 - Initialising flow: appFlow1
09.12.2015 13:27:50.322 INFO  DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy:159 - Initialising exception listener: org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy@29f0802c
09.12.2015 13:27:50.345 INFO  SedaStageLifecycleManager:69 - Initialising service: appFlow1.stage1
09.12.2015 13:27:50.584 INFO  WebServiceFactoryBean:83 - Built CXF Inbound MessageProcessor for service class com.comp.serv.ServiceEndPoindImpl
09.12.2015 13:27:50.631 INFO  ReflectionServiceFactoryBean:415 - Creating Service {http://new.webservice.namespace}ServiceForAppfrom class com.maya.serv.ServiceInterface
09.12.2015 13:27:51.839 INFO  ServerImpl:94 - Setting the server's publish address to be http://192.168.1.13:12341/appservices
09.12.2015 13:27:51.856 INFO  ComponentLifecycleManager:47 - Initialising component: component.874740624
09.12.2015 13:27:51.872 INFO  SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder:71 - Configured Mule using "org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder" with configuration resource(s): "[ConfigResource{resourceName='src/main/app/appservices.xml'}]"
09.12.2015 13:27:51.873 INFO  AutoConfigurationBuilder:71 - Configured Mule using "org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder" with configuration resource(s): "[ConfigResource{resourceName='src/main/app/appservices.xml'}]"
09.12.2015 13:27:51.873 INFO  MuleServer:289 - Mule Server starting...
09.12.2015 13:27:51.877 INFO  QueueXaResourceManager:61 - Starting ResourceManager
09.12.2015 13:27:51.878 INFO  QueueXaResourceManager:75 - Started ResourceManager
09.12.2015 13:27:51.895 INFO  AbstractLifecycleManager:72 - Disposing RegistryBroker
09.12.2015 13:27:51.899 INFO  AbstractLifecycleManager:85 - Disposing connector: connector.http.mule.default
09.12.2015 13:27:51.900 INFO  ExpiryMonitor:177 - disposing monitor
09.12.2015 13:27:51.908 INFO  MuleArtifactContext:1042 - Closing org.mule.config.spring.MuleArtifactContext@1b1473ab: startup date [Wed Dec 09 13:27:47 MSK 2015]; root of context hierarchy
09.12.2015 13:27:51.909 INFO  DefaultListableBeanFactory:444 - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@48a12036: defining beans [_muleSimpleRegistryBootstrap,_muleNotificationManager,_muleConfiguration,._muleNotificationManager:notification.1,._muleNotificationManager:notification.2,._muleNotificationManager:notification.3,._muleNotificationManager:notification.4,._muleNotificationManager:notification.5,._muleNotificationManager:notification.6,._muleNotificationManager:notification.7,._muleNotificationManager:notification.8,._muleNotificationManager:notification.9,._muleNotificationManager:notification.10,_defaultInMemoryQueueStore,_defaultPersistentQueueStore,_defaultInMemoryObjectStore,_defaultPersistentObjectStore,_defaultUserObjectStore,_defaultTransientUserObjectStore,_muleQueueManager,_muleObjectStoreManager,_defaultThreadingProfile,_defaultMessageDispatcherThreadingProfile,_defaultMessageRequesterThreadingProfile,_defaultMessageReceiverThreadingProfile,_defaultServiceThreadingProfile,_defaultRetryPolicyTemplate,_muleExpressionLanguage,_muleCustomEditorConfigurer,_muleObjectNameProcessor,_mulePropertyPlaceholderProcessor,_muleParentContextPropertyPlaceholderProcessor,_muleSystemModel,_muleAnnotationsProcessor,_muleTransformerAnnotationProcessor,_muleSecurityManager,_muleMessageProcessingManager,_muleEndpointFactory,_muleStreamCloserService,_converterResolver,_muleLockFactory,_muleLockProvider,_muleProcessingTimeWatcher,appFlow1,.appFlow1:inbound-endpoint.11,.appFlow1:jaxws-service.12,.appFlow1:jaxws-service.12:inInterceptors.13,.appFlow1:jaxws-service.12:outInterceptors.14,.appFlow1:component.15]; root of factory hierarchy
09.12.2015 13:27:51.911 INFO  FlowConstructLifecycleManager:141 - Disposing flow: appFlow1
09.12.2015 13:27:51.912 INFO  SedaStageLifecycleManager:118 - Disposing service: appFlow1.stage1
09.12.2015 13:27:51.913 INFO  ComponentLifecycleManager:82 - Disposing component: component.874740624
09.12.2015 13:27:51.914 INFO  AbstractLifecycleManager:64 - Disposing model: _muleSystemModel
09.12.2015 13:27:52.029 INFO  DefaultMuleContext:352 - 
**********************************************************************
* Mule Context shut down normally on: 09.12.15 13:27                 *
* Server was up for: 0 days, 0 hours, 0 mins, 0.144 sec              *
**********************************************************************
09.12.2015 13:27:52.031 ERROR MuleServer:451 - 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Failed to invoke lifecycle phase "start" on object: org.mule.util.queue.DelegateQueueManager@6edf29c1
Type                  : org.mule.api.lifecycle.LifecycleException
Code                  : MULE_ERROR-70228
JavaDoc               : http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/lifecycle/LifecycleException.html
********************************************************************************
Exception stack is:
1. org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteQuietly(Ljava/io/File;)Z (java.lang.NoSuchMethodError)
  org.mule.util.journal.TransactionJournalFile:149 (null)
2. Failed to invoke lifecycle phase "start" on object: org.mule.util.queue.DelegateQueueManager@6edf29c1 (org.mule.api.lifecycle.LifecycleException)
  org.mule.lifecycle.phases.DefaultLifecyclePhase:248 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/lifecycle/LifecycleException.html)
********************************************************************************
Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteQuietly(Ljava/io/File;)Z
    at org.mule.util.journal.TransactionJournalFile.clear(TransactionJournalFile.java:149)
    at org.mule.util.journal.TransactionJournal.clear(TransactionJournal.java:135)
    at org.mule.util.journal.queue.AbstractQueueTransactionJournal.clear(AbstractQueueTransactionJournal.java:121)
    at org.mule.util.journal.queue.LocalTxQueueTransactionRecoverer.recover(LocalTxQueueTransactionRecoverer.java:122)
    at org.mule.util.queue.TransactionalQueueManager.start(TransactionalQueueManager.java:92)
    at org.mule.util.queue.DelegateQueueManager.start(DelegateQueueManager.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.DefaultLifecyclePhase.applyLifecycle(DefaultLifecyclePhase.java:237)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager$RegistryLifecycleCallback.onTransition(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:273)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.invokePhase(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:152)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:123)
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistryBroker.fireLifecycle(AbstractRegistryBroker.java:76)
    at org.mule.registry.MuleRegistryHelper.fireLifecycle(MuleRegistryHelper.java:136)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:91)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:87)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.invokePhase(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:69)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:61)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleContext.start(DefaultMuleContext.java:278)
    at org.mule.MuleServer.run(MuleServer.java:290)
    at org.mule.MuleServer.start(MuleServer.java:275)
    at org.mule.MuleServer.main(MuleServer.java:134)

********************************************************************************

09.12.2015 13:27:52.032 ERROR MuleServer:465 - 
********************************************************************************
* A Fatal error has occurred while the server was running:                     *
* org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteQuietly(Ljava/io/File;)Z               *
* (java.lang.NoSuchMethodError)                                                *
*                                                                              *
* The error is fatal, the system will shutdown                                 *
********************************************************************************
```

Is this problem in POM (incompatibility libraries) and how to fix it?

**Update**
This is part of dependency tree:

```
The artifact org.apache.commons:commons-io:jar:1.3.2 has been relocated to commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.3.2
 com.comp:appservicesce:mule:1.0.17
 +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.3.2:compile
 +- fife:rsyntaxtextarea:jar:2.0.1:compile
 +- com.neovisionaries:nv-i18n:jar:1.9:compile
 +- org.apache.ibatis:ibatis-sqlmap:jar:2.3.4.726:compile
 +- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.2.2:compile
 |  \- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.3:compile
 +- com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc4:jar:4.0:compile
 +- com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0:compile
```

**UPDATE 2**
I tried ti use:
`<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>`
and
`<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>`
and
`<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>`

Result is the same: `Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteQuietly(Ljava/io/File;)Z`

Comment: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#deleteQuietly(java.io.File) deleteQuiety is around since 1.4. Check your full depenency tree for all other commons-io versions.

Comment: Jan, thank you for attetion. `mvn dependency:tree` begin with `The artifact org.apache.commons:commons-io:jar:1.3.2 has been relocated to commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.3.2`. Tree is quite big and i can't add it fully to my topic.

Comment: can you share your pom.xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mule-module-xml` dependency transitively resolves the `commons-io` dependency and for version 3.6 of mule it compiles 2.4 of commons-io

[image]

One more thing that you could try is:

```
Right click your project in Eclipse > Maven > Update Project > Force Update of Snapshots/Releases.
```

If you have mule-module-xml dependency in your pom.xml you do not need to explicitly add dependency for commons-io. Check for that too.

-Shanky G.

Comment: i did `mvn clean install -U`, doesn't help. `<mule.version>3.5.0</mule.version>`

Comment: Jan, this is my dependency tree http://pastebin.com/TjeUbn7B Please, tell me what i need to exclude?

Comment: Looking at the dependency tree, I suspect you've added the commons-io dependency on your own. Try getting rid of that dependency and let Mule itself handle that and resolve the transitive dependency for commons-io itself. If this doesn't help, can you post the pom.xml in pastebin?

Comment: Shanky, it works. Problem was in wrong host value. looks strange.

Comment: great! It would be appreciated if you could mark this as the accepted answer if it helped you resolve your issue or type in an answer on your own that worked and then select it as best answer.