# How to build and install custom Mule ESB CE runtime in Anypoint Studio

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I'm using Anypoint Studio 5.4.2 to develop Mule ESB flows targeted for Mule ESB Community Edition. I've hit a specific bug that is fixed in Mule ESB 3.7.3 - the Enterprise Edition runtime 3.7.3 is installed in Studio by default, but I want to use the Community Edition. I have checked the update site, but only 3.7.0 is available for Community Edition.

I did download the Mule ESB sources, and I'm able to build 3.7.3 community edition standalone server - that will be fine for deployment. I would like to build a Studio plugin so that I can have the 3.7.3 CE for running and testing within Studio. I have read the build instructions and browsed the source code tree, but I don't find anything pertinent - nothing interesting in the first 10 pages of Google results either.

Am I barking up the right tree here? If so, where can I find some documentation, or at least pointers, on how to get this working?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

these links might help you.

Basically, you need to change the packaging of your Mule CE project from .zip into .war so you could deploy it to tomcat.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/deploying-mule-as-a-service-to-tomcat

You should also be aware of the differences between CE and EE.

http://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/1261/anypoint-studio-esb-community-edition-how-does-it-work.html

Comment: Ralph... I think you have misunderstood my question. I'm not trying to deploy to Tomcat. I am aware of the differences between CE and EE. I want to install a 3.7.3 CE runtime into Anypoint Studio (Eclipse) for development and testing. The Mulesoft update site only provides 3.7.0 CE in addition to 3.7.3 EE. I need a bug fix that is in 3.7.3 - I can build a standalone Mule ESB runtime, but how do I install it into Anypoint Studio?

Comment: Yes, I know that. You can also test J2EE apps by building them and deploying them to a container. It's much easier to test them right from the IDE if possible. I'd like to make life easier for the team. Obviously, we can do this with 3.7.0 CE (it's there from the update site). I'd like to do it with 3.7.3 CE as well. I know I can hack it in there by installing 3.7.0 and replacing the libraries, but...

Comment: @JohnStegeman Thje other option is to run your Mule app in Eclipse as Mule App not web app. You could still get all IDE and debugger features

Comment: @CharuKhurana I *am* running it as a Mule app... in order to do that, you need the runtime installed.

Comment: @JohnStegeman I am talking about Eclipse as-is not AnypointStudio. To run in Eclipse you don't need runtime installed

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387007/creating-a-mule-project-in-eclipse/14401101#14401101

Comment: How would I do that? I know I can install the Studio plugin into Eclipse, but that uses the same runtime mechanism as Anypoint... Edit: OK, I see you have added a link. You then lose all of the niceties of Studio - might as well just use Maven and vi if you don't have the graphical editing.

Comment: Ofcourse you'd loose Studio graphical interface but still get all other IDE features and debugger - anyday better than plain editor. I developed for a long time on Eclipse when Studio wasn't as nice and very buggy. Eclipse development isn't as hard as it seems especially if you're used to XML but yes again it's a personal choice

Answer (score 0):

I am using Anypoint Studio 5.4.2 with Enterprise Edition of 3.7.2. After looking into how server runs in studio, I believe that runtime is installed as plugin at path -

```
..\AnypointStudio5\plugins\org.mule.tooling.server.3.7.2.ee_5.3.2.201511052018\mule
```

Mule core jar along with other modules are at -

```
\org.mule.tooling.server.3.7.2.ee_5.3.2.201511052018\mule\lib\mule
```

You can take a look at similar structure in your studio and see if you can replace any jar that you have fixed.

If you want to find path of mule-core-*.jar path in studio, press CTRL+T and search for class MuleServer and check the jar path.

**Edit: OR**
If you have found any bug and fixed it, then you can report bug and contribute to get it fixed officially -
https://github.com/mulesoft/mule#contribute

Comment: Manik - thanks. The bug I have found has been fixed in 3.7.3 - that's why I want to get that version into Studio. Yes, I have found the plugins folder, and I can replace an already installed version's JAR files with the one that I have built, but I was looking for a more automated way - if it was just me, no worries, but we have a team of people.

Comment: Now before curiosity kills the cat, I got Mule CE 3.7.3 from https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/releases/tag/mule-3.7.3 and I see it has maven builds for studio, standalone and embedded. I tried building studio distribution but it gave me error (must be because of firewall rules I have here). I was wondering if you already tried that build `\mule-mule-3.7.3\distributions\studio` and see what it outputs, if plugin to import in studio?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it. There is an issue with the assembly whitelist in the Standalone distribution - which needs to be built before building the studio distribution. Once you fix that issue, the studio distribution builds fine. It creates a .tar.gz file with /lib and /src directories - alas, no Eclipse metadata. I have poked around all of the mulesoft stuff on github, and I cannot find anything appropriate (I think we need a mule server tooling project).